# How to cutomise a CentOS iso to include my own rpm packages

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

Say I have downloaded a CentOS live desktop CD. How would I include my own rpm packages, so that they get installed automatically as soon as I boot with the live CD or have it permanently install in my system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CentOS have great documentation on how to use Kickstart files in order to achieve what you want.

I don't see the point in copy/pasting that entire page, so I'll just link to it: https://projects.centos.org/trac/livecd/wiki/KickstartFile

> The kickstart file can include some basic system configuration items,
> the package manifest and a script to be run **at the end of the build
> process.**

It falls under automated installations: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html

#### What are Kickstart Installations?

> Many system administrators would prefer to use an automated
> installation method to install Red Hat Enterprise Linux on their
> machines. To answer this need, Red Hat created the kickstart
> installation method. Using kickstart, a system administrator can
> create a single file containing the answers to all the questions that
> would normally be asked during a typical installation.
>
> Kickstart files can be kept on a single server system and read by
> individual computers during the installation. This installation method
> can support the use of a single kickstart file to install Red Hat
> Enterprise Linux on multiple machines, making it ideal for network and
> system administrators.
>
> Kickstart provides a way for users to automate a Red Hat Enterprise
> Linux installation.

Comment: Cool! will look into it.

Comment: This works even better when net-booting. Hook up a central server that hands out images, and kickstart files.